# Create new log file each run in logback?

Tags: java, logback

How to create new log file each time application runs?

I would like to keep previous logs in any way. For example, I would prefer to name each new log file by time and date it was created. Otherwise, I agree to backup old log file into date and time filename.

Unfortunately, I can't see appropriate policies and/or triggers here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

**UPDATE**

I made approximately as said in "duplicate"

```
    <appender name="ROUTINEAPPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/routine.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/routine%d{yyyyMMdd}%d{HHmmss,aux}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="com.inthemoon.toolkit.StartupTimeBasedTriggeringPolicy" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %C{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

but my class `com.inthemoon.toolkit.StartupTimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` is never called. I put breakpoint in `start()` method but it never raised.

Also, no rolling occurs. Log file is created, but it always has the name `routine.log`.

Also I don't understand, how parameters `file` and `filenamePattern` should coexist.

**UPDATE 2**

I have fixed `UPDATE 1` class reference, but still don't have what I need. In given solution, the date time is inserted into OLD log filename. For example, if I ran program in 2013, it created `routine.log`. Then I waited a year and run program in 2014. New log file will be created and have name `routine.log`, while OLD 2013 log will be put into `routine2014XXXXXXXXXX.log`, which is absolutely irrelevant.

I need create new file each time program starts and have this namely file marked with date-time stamp.

Answer (score 15):

The following configuration will create a new logfile and console output every time the program is run, please note that it does not use RollingFileAppender. For more information please refer to logback documentation https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

```
<configuration>
    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logfile-${bySecond}.txt</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"></appender-ref>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What if two processes using this are invoked less than 1 second (or even millisecond) apart?

Comment: that file will create every time and not only once when service starts

Comment: Change: <append>true</append> to FALSE !!!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to continue using `RollingFileAppender` you can create your own `TriggeringPolicy` which will always trigger a new log file to be generated upon it's first call.

```
@NoAutoStart
public class StartupTriggeringPolicy<E> extends TriggeringPolicyBase<E> {
    private boolean triggerRollover = true;

    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(final File activeFile, final E event) {
        if (!triggerRollover) { return false; }
        triggerRollover = false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can then set the `triggeringPolicy` property within you `logback.xml`'s `<appender>` configuration:

```
<appender name="startupRolloverAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <triggeringPolicy class="com.your.package.StartupTriggeringPolicy"/>
    <!-- other configurations -->
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

This configuration creates the output log file every time it runs.  Notice the append attribute set to false.

```
  <appender name="FIXED_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${LOGPATH}/A3.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>info</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

Comment: `<append>false</append>` simply overwrites existing log file without preserving its content in any way.