# Zip the complete logs directory via logback.xml

Tags: java, logback

is there any way i can zip the previous logs directory if exists and start fresh(creating new dir everytime system starts) in slf4j with logback.xml ?

PS: I am using java7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the help of logback. Rolling policy is for that purpose. Set the retantion days and the pass for storing the zip log. MaxHistory  amount of days after the file will be archived.

```
   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/yourLog.log</file>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>../../logs/backup/yourLog_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</FileNamePattern>
        <MaxHistory>32</MaxHistory>
      </rollingPolicy>
   </appender>
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. However i am looking to zip the whole directory and start fresh.

Comment: @Mike you are welcome ;) you could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844215/create-new-log-file-each-run-in-logback    but I can not find zipping folder :) Could you let me know if you find it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Logback do not have any out of the box functionality to create zip from achieved log folder. However you shell script (Unix) or batch script (Windows) and schedule it to run as per needed timeline.