# logback: How to create a file for each execution while also checking the size and maximum number of files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logging, logback

I have a spring boot application and I would like to have logback create a log file, with the current date (including minutes hours and seconds).
So there will be a file for each time the application is run.

To do this I did this:

```
<springProperty name="log_path_folder" source="log.path.folder"/>
<property name="application_filename" value="application"/>
<timestamp key="currentDate" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH.mm.ss"/>

<appender name="APPLICATION_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${log_path_folder}/${application_filename}-${currentDate}.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level [%marker] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<root level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION_FILE"/>
</root>
```

This works correctly. The problem is that I don't know how to add checks on a maximum number of files or on the maximum size of the folder with all the logs.
I know it is possible to use the RollingFileAppender. The problem is that if I put the seconds in the filename, it creates a file for every minute. So I won't have all the logs of a run in one file.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to keep only specific numbers of log files inside your logging folder, there is a parameter you can set: ***MaxBackupIndex***

By setting this, say we set to 2.
Your log files under your log folder will only have at most three logs, which are:

1. logging.log4j
2. logging.log4j.1
3. logging.log4j.2

You can check out to [Article from baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-rolling-file-appenders) or [Apache logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with onboard resources, but there is a discussion on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844215/create-new-log-file-each-run-in-logback) about custom implementations.

The `RollingFileAppender` rotates under certain circumstances, but not on application start or something you would need. The `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` uses a `triggeringPolicy` to determine when to rotate. There is only the `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` to rotate based on the size of a file. But you can write you own policy as discussed on the other thread mentioned above.

At least those are my findings after looking into the [manual of logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).

---

About your problem with rotating on application start found [this](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#uniquelyNamed) in the manual. It works with other appenders as well, but I couldn't figure out how to rotate the way you want it.

```
<timestamp key="time" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSS"/>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- use the previously created timestamp to create a uniquely
         named log file -->
    <file>logs/log-${time}.txt</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

By using the timestamp with seconds, as you already did. I tested it and works on my machine. I added the milliseconds to be more precise.

You can also tell logback to use the application start time as timestamp by setting the `timeReference` to `contextBirth`:

```
<timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" 
         timeReference="contextBirth"/>
```